# Observable Interval without drift

Tags: rxjs

I am using Observable.interval to schedule code execuiton at specified times:

```
let obs =  Observable.interval(50).subscribe(()=>{
  console.log(this.currentFrame+" "+new Date().getTime());
  this.currentFrame++
});
```

This is the output. As you can see, after 6 iterations I already have a 10ms drift. How can I use Observable.interval, but also specify that it needs to recalculate next iteration based on the current drift?

```
 0 1513972329849
 1 1513972329901
 2 1513972329952
 3 1513972330004
 4 1513972330057
 5 1513972330110
```

Comment: See [this RxJS fix](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3044) which was reverted because it exposed [this bug](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/935) in Angular's Zone.js.

Comment: Actually, that Zone.js bug was related to the PR, but that bug did not effect the error that resulted in the PR's reversion. There is an explanation [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3152#issuecomment-354638226) if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Until @cartant's fix gets repulled, you could use [`expand`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html) and create the behavior yourself. Assuming `delay` will always drift forward, try the following:

```
function correcting_interval(interval) {
  const start_time = new Date().getTime();
  return Observable.of(-1)
                   .expand(v => Observable.of(v + 1).delay(interval - (new Date().getTime() - start_time) % interval))
                   .skip(1);
}
```